# Catching 4xx and code errors separately with axios using then / catch syntax

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-promise

I have been reading up on Promises and the `then/catch` syntax.

[This article](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-promises-in-depth) was very comprehensive and I thought I understood:

```
fetch()
  .then()
  .catch()
```

Here, `catch()` deals with errors which get thrown in code called within `then()`.

```
var p = fetch()
p.then()
p.catch()
```

This would properly catch errors thrown by `fetch()` and process the correct response of `fetch()` within `then()`.

Why is the behavior different in axios?

Here all examples I found use the first method to catch errors thrown by an `axios()` call. The result is that in

```
axios(/* axios stuff */)
  .then(successCallback)
  .catch(errorCallback)
```

errorCallback handles 4xx errors thrown by `axios()` but also any runtime errors thrown by `successCallback`. Or am I missing something here? Is there a way to separate these two classes of errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise link is like water flow. The last `catch` will catch all errors thrown before it if there's no handler in any front then's second argument

If you don't want `errorCallback` to handle errors thrown by `successCallback`, you should put errorCallback to then's second argument.

```
axios(/* axios stuff */)
  .then(successCallback, errorCallback)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was missing! I am confused why this is not the preferred way to deal with axios errors. Most examples use `.then()` and `.catch()`.